# Error in function frees from a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, operating-system

I'm having trouble finding the error of my code ...

I get a memory address as a parameter and need to release from my list (HEAP)

List structure:

```
typedef struct free_node {
    size_t free;
    size_t size;
    struct free_node *next;
} free_node_t;

typedef struct {
  free_node_t *head;
  free_node_t *lastAlloca; // Usado para next fit
} free_list_t;
```

I need to do a function that releases the ptr memory address

```
void libera(void *ptr) {

    free_node_t *metaData = (void*)ptr - sizeof(free_node_t);
    assert(HEAP->lastAlloca != NULL);
    free_node_t *listNavigator = HEAP->head;

    while(listNavigator != NULL) {  
        if(listNavigator->next == metaData) {   
            listNavigator->next = metaData->next;
            listNavigator->free += metaData->size + metaData->free + sizeof(free_node_t);
            break;
        }       
        listNavigator = listNavigator->next;
    }
}
```

But, it is not working. When I compile for some cases of segmentation fault.

Please, help me :)

Comment: `free()` is a function which releases memory which you allocated, see here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm

Comment: You can't do pointer arithmetic with a `void *` pointer. You need to cast it to a type like `char *`.

Comment: But, I need to implement the free

Comment: You're doing your own memory management instead of using `malloc()` and `free()`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The allocation worked, I'm having problems in the free

Comment: I think we need to see the allocation code — in fact, a complete MCVE ([MCVE]).  What you're doing is looking odd.  It might be OK, but you'll be doing some moderately esoteric allocation if the freeing code is OK.

Comment: I see no trace of `free(3)` function call in your code.  It's difficult to see what you intend to do with free if you post all the code but the one in which you use it.  Follow @JonathanLeffler and post a MCVE.  Edit your question to include a complete example with a trace of a sample run.  OH WELL, libera() is the implementation of free() sorry.  But anyway, follow the recommendation of Jonathan, just before.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to implement a tracking memory allocator. To get at the offset of your metadata, you have to use a temporary pointer, like so:

```
void libera(void *ptr) {

    free_node_t *temp = (free_node_t*)ptr;
    free_node_t *metaData = temp - sizeof(free_node_t);
    assert(HEAP->lastAlloca != NULL);
    free_node_t *listNavigator = HEAP->head;

    while(listNavigator != NULL) {  
        if(listNavigator->next == metaData) {   
            listNavigator->next = metaData->next;
            listNavigator->free += metaData->size + metaData->free + sizeof(free_node_t);
            break;
        }       
        listNavigator = listNavigator->next;
    }
}
```

Your cast `free_node_t *metaData = (void*)ptr - sizeof(free_node_t);` doesn't do anything since `ptr` is passed as a void pointer, and you can't decrement a void pointer.

Comment: *that should have told you that you can't dereference a cast pointer*  . .what?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Sorry for the confusion; I removed the side note about what I suspected and limited the answer to the information in the question.

Comment: There was no issue as such with the note, just the term "cast pointer" is not valid. I think you meant void pointer.

Comment: No, a pointer that has been cast to a different type is a cast pointer. "Cast" is both the present-tense and past-tense of the verb "to cast". I realize that some use the term "casted", but that is not grammatically correct.